# Swap Pie Chart Values

Tags: excel, charts

Creating a Personal Budget in Excel and want to swap the data values so I get the % saved and not the % of income spent.

Right now the Data is: ='Chart Data'!$B$4:$B$5 and swapping b4 and b5 doesn't work. This is extremely unintuitive. I don't understand where this magical 'Chart Data' resides. I've tried to just use the two cells I want, F6 and F12, and that doesn't work either.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to copy the Data Label to show the % saved instead of the % spent. I realized I wasn't trying to swap values in the pie chart; wouldn't make a difference. I was simply trying to *label* the pie chart differently.